# Macro to Toggle Alternate Colour Rows

Tags: emeditor

The ability to set different colour rows is great, but would it be possible to set this temporarily on/off any file (so it can then potentially be assigned to a button that could be toggled on the menu bar)? The ability to do something similar to the Hide Quotes Temporarily button would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the following macro.

```
r = 255;   // red of even number background
g = 255;   // green of even number background
b = 128;    // blue of even number background
rgbCustom = r + (g << 8) + (b << 16);
cfg = document.Config;
mode = cfg.Display.ColorList.Item( 100 ).BackMode;   // get Background Mode of 100th color (even lines)
if( mode == 2 ) {   // 2 : Transparent
    cfg.Display.ColorList.Item( 100 ).BackMode = 0;  // set Background Mode as Custom
    cfg.Display.ColorList.Item( 100 ).BackColor = rgbCustom;  // set Background color
}
else {
    cfg.Display.ColorList.Item( 100 ).BackMode = 2;  // set Background Mode as Transparent, don't care Background color
}
cfg.Save();
```

To run this, save this code as, for instance, `ToggleAlternateColour.jsee`, and then select this file from **Select...** in the **Macros** menu. Finally, select **Run ToggleAlternateColour.jsee** in the **Macros** menu.

To assign this macro as a button in the basic toolbar, you can double-click the basic toolbar (or select **Customize Toolbars** on the **Tools** menu, select `Untitled (Toolbar 1)` in the **Basic Toolbars** list, and click **Customize**). In the **Customize Toolbar** dialog box, find `ToggleAlternateColour.jsee` from the left list box, and click **Add**.